# Why are these custom new and delete allocators behaving like this?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

There are two problems I'm having with the following code. One is that my custom operator delete function is not being called, particularly the array version, but only for a custom class as opposed to an int type. The other issue is I'm is that I want to understand why there's an extra 8 bytes allocated only for the custom class array but not the built-in type array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;


struct TestClass
{
    uint32_t m;
    TestClass() {
        std::cout << "TestClass Constructor called\n";
    }
    ~TestClass()
    {
        std::cout << "TestClass Destructor called\n";
    }
};


size_t allocatedMemory = 0;

// Single version new
void* operator new(size_t count)
{
    void* mem = malloc(count);
    if (!mem) 
        throw bad_alloc();
    else
    {
        allocatedMemory += count;
        cout << "void operator new(size_t count) called with " << count << " size\n";

        return mem;
    }
}
// Array version new
void* operator new[](size_t count)
{
    void* mem = malloc(count);
    if (!mem)
        throw bad_alloc();
    else
    {
        allocatedMemory += count;
        cout << "void operator new[](size_t count) called with " << count << " size\n";

        return mem;
    }

}

// Single version delete
void operator delete(void* mem, size_t size)
{
    allocatedMemory -= size;
    free(mem);
    cout << "void operator delete(void* mem, size_t size) called with " << size << " size\n";
}
// Array version delete
void operator delete[](void* mem, size_t size)
{
    allocatedMemory -= size;
    free(mem);
    cout << "void operator delete[](void* mem, size_t size) called with " << size << " size\n";
}


int main()
{
    // WITH CUSTOM CLASS TYPE
    //=====================================
    cout << "Single TestClass:\n";
    TestClass* testObj = new TestClass; // operator new(size_t count) called with size of 4
    delete testObj; // operator delete(void* mem, size_t size) called with size of 4
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "TestClass array:\n";
    TestClass* testObjArray = new TestClass[5]; // operator new[](size_t count) called with size of 28
                                                // An extra 8 bytes
    delete[] testObjArray; // operator delete[](void* mem, size_t size) called with size of 28;
                            // An extra 8 bytes

    cout << "\n";

    // WITH BUILT-IN TYPE INT
    //=====================================
    cout << "Single uint32_t:\n";
    uint32_t* fourByteInt = new uint32_t; // operator new(size_t count) called with size of 4
                                        // Same as with single class TestClass object
    delete fourByteInt; // operator delete(void* mem, size_t size) called with size of 4
                        // Same as with single class TestClass object

    cout << "\n";

    cout << "uint32_t array:\n";
    uint32_t* fourByteIntArray = new uint32_t[5]; // operator new[](size_t count) called with size of 20
                                                // 8 bytes less than with the array of TestClass
    
    delete[]fourByteIntArray; // None of my operator functions called at all


}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why isn't my void delete[](void* mem, size_t size) function called at all when deleting the array of the
   built-in type uint32_t? My function IS called when deleting the array of the TestClass objects.
2. Why is it allocating 28 bytes instead of 20 bytes only for the TestClass array? I assume the extra 8 bytes holds
   information about how long the array is so that it knows how much memory to free, but isn't this information
   required whether the array is of a built-in/POD/whatever it's called data type or a custom type?

Comment: For your second question: `operator new[]` uses an implementation-defined overhead for the size information (as you suspect) so that deletion can know how many destructors need to be invoked. If a type is trivially destructible (meaning the destructor does not _need_ to be invoked), the compiler _could theoretically_ avoid this extra overhead; but this would be an implementation-defined behavior, and I have never actually seen this occur. Generally it's better to ignore / not overload `operator new[]` at all, for this reason.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I don't get it. When you want to delete an array of int you pass a pointer to the first int to the delete function, that's all it gets, a pointer. So how does it know how many elements to delete or how much memory to free?

Comment: @Zebrafish  meta-data usually before the returned allocated block (implementation specific detail)

Comment: For the first question, there is an overload `operator delete[](void *)`  that may be called for trivial types instead of the `operator delete(void *, size_t)` that you have defined.   For the second case, the machinery of a `delete` expression needs to explicitly call the destructor of your class a correct number of times, so needs to store that value.   Again, for a basic type, an implementation does not need to store the number of values to be released.

Comment: @RichardCritten When you delete an array of int you the delete function only gets a pointer to the first int. It needs to know how many elements there are or how much memory to free. Presumably this would be stored in the metadata, but the int array doesn't have it? Then when passing int array pointer to the delete function how does it know how much memory to release?

Comment: @Zebrafish The metadata is stored *before* the array that is returned. The internal machinery to array allocations will offset the pointer _before_ it returns it to you from `new[]` so you never see this, and will readjust to read it during `delete[]`ion. To the consumer, they just see a pointer; but the implementation knows how to read the value that's stored along side it. If you ever play around with placement-new with arrays, you will see an integer (usually `size_t` in size) stored before the start of the array in memory

Comment: @Zebrafish (implementation specific) - delete subtracts the size of the meta-data header from the passed pointer.  This adjusted pointer now points to the meta-data structure.

Comment: @RichardCritten What I don't understand is that this extra metadata is required to know how large of an area of memory was allocated and needs to be free (or the number of elements). This is the case for the custom non-trivial classes and plain types like int, right? The TestClass array shows it getting an extra 8 bytes, but the int array, not?

Comment: @Zebrafish What the overhead is, and _whether the overhead even exists_ is *implementation defined*. The compiler is free to choose how much overhead is used for metadata (if any) -- so there is no correct answer for the C++ standard, there is only a correct answer for a *specific compiler*. Since most `new` implementations typically use `malloc` internally, it's not a huge surprise if they were to elide the extra length size since `malloc` doesn't request the size (because  it already tracks this internally)

Comment: @Human-Compiler I see. Well I'm happy to just accept that it's implementation defined and I can't see what's going on under the hood. I suppose the more pressing problem is the other issue, which is that for some reason when I delete[ ] the int array it doesn't seem to want to call the delete[ ] function that also takes a size, and so I can't subtract it from my 'memoryAllocated' variable. I wish I could I understand this better, from the documentation it seems that which one it calls isn't specified when it's trivially destructible.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to define

```
void operator delete(void* mem)
```

and

```
void operator delete[](void* mem)
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

> 5-6) Called instead of (1-2) if a user-defined replacement is provided,
> except that it's unspecified whether (1-2) or (5-6) is called when
> deleting objects of incomplete type and arrays of non-class and
> trivially-destructible class types.

Here (1-2) are the versions of delete without a size parameter, and (5-6) are the versions of delete with a size parameter. So it's unspecified which version of delete is called for an array of `uint32_t`.

Comment: So because int is trivially destructible either the size version of the new function or the version without 'size' can be called? But my int array deletion doesn't call size version, but the single int deletion does? Is it just chance which one gets called? In my case where the size version isn't called, how do I get the size freed so I can minus it from the 'memoryAllocated' variable?

Comment: @Zebrafish *Arrays* of non-class types. A single int isn't an array. As for getting the size, there is no platform independent way AFAIK.